# Optimization of a function of 2 parameters

Tags: r, optimization

My problem is probably common, but I don't know how to adapt the answer to this problem

I have a function F with two parameters (a,b) and I have to find the maximum of this function.

For now, I do that :

```
optimization_of_F<-function(a,b){
  solution=c(0,0,0) #initialization 
  a=seq(0, 5, by=0.1)
  b=seq(0.1, 5, by =0.1)

  for (d in a){ 
    for (k  in b){ 
      if  ( F(d, k) > solution[1] )  {
        solution[1]= F(d,k)
        solution[2]= d
        solution[3]= k
      }  
    }     
  }
  return(solution)
}
```

But this way is too long and I'd like to optimize it. How can I do that ?

Comment: Do you realize you are overwriting `solution` in all but the last iteration of the loop?

Comment: Also, don't call a function `F` since that means `FALSE`

Comment: I'm just writing solution if it's better than the temporary solution.

Answer (score 7):

Try this, where `F` is your function, `c(0,0)` an initial guess, `c=2` and `d=pi/3` are fixed parameters fed to `F`,

```
optim(c(0,0), F, c=2, d=pi/3)
```

Comment: How can I use "optim" if my function F have others parameters ?

Example : F(a,b,c,d) with c and d  fix by me.

Comment: I made a test but it doesn't work.


`test<-function(a, b, c){
  sum= a + b + c
  return(sum)
}


optim(c(0,0), test, c=1 )`

Comment: `optim` will only optimise the first parameter of `F`, so it needs to be the vector `c(a,b)`. Try `F = function(p=c(1,1), c=1){(p[1] - c)^2 + (p[2]-2*c)^2}`

Comment: the Examples section of https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html are quite helpful as well (`?optim`).

Answer (score 2):

I feel like this will get you closer to what you are looking for:

```
a=seq(0, 5, by=0.1)
b=seq(0.1, 5, by =0.1)
outer(a, b, FUN=F)
```

Comment: It seems to work. Is there a way to keep the value of a and b in the outer matrix ?

Comment: Sort of. You can do `rownames(MatrixName) <- a` and same with `colnames`. You can also build an `array`, essentially a matrix where each cell has three values.