# Finding Global Minimum

Tags: r, optimization

I am trying to find global minimum (-5 <= (x,y) <= 5) using the function below. When I use optimize, getting "Error in T %*% x : non-conformable arguments". Am I doing to something wrong?

```
T = qr.Q(qr(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=T)))

fitness = function(x){
  z = T%*%x+c(.5,.5);
  s = 100*(z[1]^2-z[2])^2 + (z[1]-1)^2;
  return(10*(s/4000-cos(s))+10)
}
```

```
optimize(fitness, c(-0.5, 0.5),  upper = c(5,5), lower = c(-5,-5))
Error in T %*% x : non-conformable arguments
```

Comment: `x` is a scalar, if you put a `print(x)` as the first code line in the function it prints `[1] -1.18034`.

Comment: If I just run it as below, it is working fine. 
x1 = c(-0.5,0.5);
fitness(x1)

> fitness(x1)
[1] 14.43038

Comment: Yes, but `fitness` is called with scalar `x` by `optimize`.

Comment: Thanks Rui. I am bit confused.  So do I need to add x = as.vector(x) to the function so it will convert the arg as vector? I tried that too, still having the same issue.

Comment: Try `optim(c(0,0), fitness)`. Or any other initial value of your choice.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15486612/optimization-of-a-function-of-2-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are using `optimize()` (good for 1D optimization problems) on a 2D optimization problem.

As indicated by Rui Barradas you should use `optim()` (which is used for multi-dimensional optimization problems).

The following works:

```
T = qr.Q(qr(matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)))

fitness = function(x){
  z = T%*%x+c(.5,.5);
  s = 100*(z[1]^2-z[2])^2 + (z[1]-1)^2;
  return(10*(s/4000-cos(s))+10)
}

fitness.optim = optim(c(-0.5, 0.5),  fitness)
```

where `fitness.optim` results in:

```
> fitness.optim
$par
[1] -0.4550863  0.5470252

$value
[1] 0.298451

$counts
function gradient 
      59       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

So, the optimum (minimum) `fitness` value is found at `x_opt = fitness.optim$par` i.e. `x_opt = c(-0.4550863, 0.5470252)` achieving the value `fitness.optim$value = 0.298451`.

Comment: There are many local minima but how to I say that my result is a global minima? Also on the domain -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5. I am trying to loop through but not sure to say particular value is a global minima.

Comment: Well, that is difficult to answer. Since this is a 2D problem, the answer may be easier than in a higher-order optimization problem, since you could plot the function to minimize as a function of the two variables (creating a surface plot for instance --using the `persp()` function in the `graphics` package or the `plot_ly()` function in the `plotly` package) and with appropriate domain knowledge you could tell whether it's a global minimum or not.